# CSS Layout completely messed up in IE 11

Tags: html, css, layout, internet-explorer-11

I've been working on a midterm site for my current Web Development class and have encountered a problem I haven't been able to find a solution to. IE11 (and possibly earlier versions) don't seem to like my layout and I'm not sure why. Everything displays fine in Firefox and Chrome. This is the link: http://auharvey.com/1510/midterm/index.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```css
#wrapper {
 width: 800px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color: #855321;

 }
 
body {
 background-color: #e6c6a6;
 font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
 }

header, nav, main, footer {
 display: block;
 } 
 
/* a:link {
 color: #855321;
 }
 
a:hover {
 color: #4c9860;
 }
 
a:visited {
 color: #855321;
 }
  */
header {
 background-color: #cc9966;
 border: 3px solid #855321;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 10px;
 
 }
 
nav {
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0;
 height: 24px;
 border: 3px solid #855321;
 
 }

nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 
 padding: 0;

 margin: 0;
 }
  
nav li {
 display: inline;
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0;
 }
 
nav a {
 display:inline-block;
 width: 262px;
 height: 24px;
 background-color: #cc9966;
 color: #855321;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 24px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }
 
nav a:hover {
 background-color: #4c9860;
 color: #855321;
 }
 
nav a:visited {
 color: #855321;
 }
 
#container {
 width: 800px;
 background-color: #ff0000;
 }
 
main {
 display: block;
 min-height: 290px;
 background-color: #cc9966;
 border: 3px solid #855321;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 10px;
 }
 
#main-right {
 float: right;
 width: 374px;
 min-height: 290px;
 background-color: #cc9966;
 border: 3px solid #855321;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 10px;
 }

.highlight {
 background-color: #4c9860;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: italic;
 }

.float-left {
 float: left;
 width: 374px;
 }
 
.float-right {
 float: right;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 10px 5px 10px 10px;
 }
 
ul {
 list-style-type: square;
 line-height: 150%;
 }
 
footer {
 clear: both;
 background-color: #cc9966;
 border: 3px solid #855321;
 font-size: small;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Enoch Treadwell's Trash Service</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
 <header role="banner">
  <h1>Enoch Treadwell's Trash Service</h1>
 </header>
 <nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <div id="container">
  <main role="main" class="float-left">
   <h3>Who We Are</h3>
   <p>Enoch Treadwell's Trash Service is the new option in your town for all your trash disposal needs! Weather your looking for a weekly trash pick up or just a one time pick up by appointment we are the best choice!  We offer great rates on all our trash disposal services!  We even have a special offer for year contracts for weekly pick-up service at the low price of 15.99 a month!  Please visit our convenient location at blah blah blah or give us a call at (999) 555-1234 between the hours of 8 to 5 M-F or 10 to 2 on Saturday.<p>
  </main>
  
  <div id="main-right">
  <img src="special2.png" class="float-right" width="100" alt="Specials">
   <h3>Specials</h3>
   
   <ul>
    <li><span class="highlight">10% OFF</span> Dumpster Rental for bulk</li>
    <li><span class="highlight">$15.99 </span> a month for Weekly Pick-Up with a one year contact.</li>
    <li><span class="highlight">20% OFF</span> Pre-Sorted Recyclables</li>
    <li>Discounted rates for Monday pick-ups.</li>
   </ul>
   
  </div>
 </div>
 <footer role="contentinfo">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a> &#124; <a href="services.html">Services</a> &#124; <a href="contact.html">Contact</a><br>
  Copyright &copy; 2014 Alyssa Harvey<br>
  <a href="mailto:aharvey3869@student.gwinnetttech.edu">aharvey3869@student.gwinnetttech.edu</a>
 </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace main with the following code. Seems you are missing an ending p tag

```
<main role="main" class="float-left">
            <h3>Who We Are</h3>
            <p>Enoch Treadwell's Trash Service is the new option in your town for all your trash disposal needs! Weather your looking for a weekly trash pick up or just a one time pick up by appointment we are the best choice!  We offer great rates on all our trash disposal services!  We even have a special offer for year contracts for weekly pick-up service at the low price of 15.99 a month!  Please visit our convenient location at blah blah blah or give us a call at (999) 555-1234 between the hours of 8 to 5 M-F or 10 to 2 on Saturday.</p>
        </main>
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much. I'm surprised it passed W3C validation like that! Next time I'll be sure to check it over more thoroughly myself even if it passes validation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i can't comment because i don't have my 50 Reputations, but here's an additional tip:

Don't user Pixel (px) so your website is mor flexible for Displays with much smaller Width/height.

define in your body{} in the css:

```
    body{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
    }
```

and use for font size in other classes/ids this:

```
    #example{
    font-size: 1em;
    }
```

Here is em equal to the normal font-size defined in the body{}.

1 em = normal font size.

2 em = font-size * 2...

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html